# Windows Phone SDK 8.0 is taking too long to install

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am installing windows phone SDK 8.0 but its taking too long. From the last 3 hours its almost 25% and now not progressing further. I cancel it. Whats the problem. Is there is any issue with operating system or Visual Studio. I have following versions

Windows : Windows 8.1 Pro

Visual Studio: 2013

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Today's HDDs have write performance of about 100MB/s, more if you are on SSD. 3 hours means over 1000 gigabytes worth of data written, where actual size of the SDK is probably 1/1000th of that. It shows how inefficient todays software has become. What is this setup even doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is big in size. It would take a little longer to download and install.
If you have cancelled and you restart the download the setup will resume from the point you have cancelled it.